# what's wrong in this code for insertion sort?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, insertion-sort

i created one insertion sort code using nested for. just because I'm writing condition in if part separately inside for loop, it gives me different answers. please tell me what's wrong with my approach.

i tried searching online but i did not get the result
this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j;
    int arr[] = {32, 5, 45, 8, 17, 82, 10};
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    
    printf("Before Sorting: ");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        int key = arr[i];
        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
        {
            if(arr[j] > key)
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
        }
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
    
    printf("\nAfter Sorting: ");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Different answers from what?

Comment: At the end of the inner loop, `j` will always be `-1`. So `arr[j+1] = key` is always doing `arr[0] = key`. How can that be right?

Comment: Try following the algorithm by hand on a piece of paper, you should see the problems.

Comment: thank you sir. i was doing that only. i didnt break the inner loop when i found the desired position of the key.

Comment: You forgot to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the nested for loops

```
for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    int key = arr[i];
    for (j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
    {
        if(arr[j] > key)
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
    }
    arr[j + 1] = key;
}
```

is that `arr[0]` is always set to `key` because after the inner for loop `j` is equal to `-1`.

You could rewrite them for example like

```
for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    int key = arr[i];
    j = i - 1;

    for ( ; j >= 0 && key < arr[j]; --j )
    {
        arr[j+1] = arr[j];
    }    

    arr[j+1] = key;
}
```

Pay attention to that the type of the value produced by the operator sizeof has type `size_t`. So it will be more correctly to write

```
size_t size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
```

Also you should declare variables in minimum scopes where they are used.

I would write the program the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int arr[] = { 32, 5, 45, 8, 17, 82, 10 };
    size_t size = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( arr[0] );

    printf( "Before Sorting: " );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", arr[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < size; i++ )
    {
        if (arr[i] < arr[i - 1])
        {
            int key = arr[i];

            size_t j = i;

            for ( ; j != 0 && key < arr[j-1]; --j )
            {
                arr[j] = arr[j -1];
            }

            arr[j] = key;
        }
    }

    printf( "\nAfter Sorting: " );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", arr[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```